# Logging does not show text for level under ERROR level

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I am new to logging. I want to make a test of logging. Here are pom and log4j2 :

```
  ...
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

log4j2.xml in src/main/resources :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p ${hostName} --- [%15.15t] %-40.40c{1.} : %m%n%ex
        </Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="FileAppender" fileName="/opt/oxalys/logs/oxalysCronsLog.log"
            filePattern="/opt/oxalys/logs/oxalysLog-%d{yyyyMMdd}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB" />
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
        </RollingFile>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.axian.oxalys" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
        </Logger>

        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
            <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

application.properties in src/main/resources :

```
logging.level.root=TRACE
logging.level.com.axian.oxalys=TRACE
```

App code for testing logging :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.axian.oxalys.*")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.axian.oxalys.*")
public class App {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(App.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        logger.debug("Debugging log");
        logger.info("Info log");
        logger.warn("Hey, This is a warning!");
        logger.error("Oops! We have an Error. OK");
        logger.fatal("Damn! Fatal error. Please fix me.");
    }
}
```

When running the project then console displays only :

```
11:47:38.371 [main] ERROR com.axian.oxalys.main.App - Oops! We have an Error. OK
11:47:38.378 [main] FATAL com.axian.oxalys.main.App - Damn! Fatal error. Please fix me.
```

So what is wrong ?

**edit :**

here is entire pom :

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.axian.oxalys</groupId>
        <artifactId>axian-oxalys</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0-Snapshot</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>axian-oxalys-root</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Axian Oxalys POM Parent</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <description>POM parent du projet, regroupe toutes les dépendances, modules, versions etc.</description>
    <!-- Versions des dépendances utilisées dans le projet -->
    <properties>
        <project.version>2.3.0-Snapshot</project.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <maven.plugin.version>3.3</maven.plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <spring-boot.version>2.1.1.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
        <json.version>20160212</json.version>
        <json.simple.version>1.1</json.simple.version>
        <tomcat.version>8.0.24</tomcat.version>
        <easymock.version>2.4</easymock.version>
        <reporting-plugin-jxr.version>2.5</reporting-plugin-jxr.version>
        <reporting-plugin-pmd.version>3.5</reporting-plugin-pmd.version>
        <reporting-surefire.version>2.18.1</reporting-surefire.version>
        <reporting-cobertura.version>2.7</reporting-cobertura.version>
        <apache.poi.version>3.14</apache.poi.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <jsf.version>2.2.12</jsf.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <!-- Les dépendances utilisées -->
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Spring boot -->
            <!-- Dépendances utiles uniquement pour les tests -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
                <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
                <version>${hsqldb.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Accès aux données -->
            <!-- jpa -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Journalisation de l'application <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId> <version>${spring-boot.version}</version> 
                </dependency> -->
            <!-- Sécurité -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                <version>${json.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
                <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
                <version>${json.simple.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
                <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
                <version>${easymock.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                <version>${apache.poi.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                <version>${apache.poi.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Batch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Accès aux données -->
        <!-- jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Journalisation de l'application -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Sécurité -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Dépendances web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>apacheds-server-jndi</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- COMMONS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-exec</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>axian-oxalys</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>/**</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${reporting-plugin-pmd.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                        <linkXRef>true</linkXRef>
                        <sourceEncoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</sourceEncoding>
                        <targetJdk>${java.version}</targetJdk>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${reporting-plugin-jxr.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${reporting-surefire.version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${reporting-cobertura.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <formats>
                        <format>xml</format>
                    </formats>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: This works for me. Can you please show the whole pom.xml?

Comment: I edited the post to include the entire pom.xml

Comment: As I understand you are deploying the app as WAR. Could there be a log4j2.xml anywhere in the app server?

Comment: there is `log4j-api-2.7.jar` in tomcat directory but inside another folder ( wtpwebapps )

Comment: Can you check the generated WAR file if your log4j2.xml is included correctly?

Comment: how to make this checking ?

Comment: You can extract the JAR with an unzipper. JAR is ZIP format

Comment: there is no `log4j` cause it references a parent : `<relativePath>../axian-oxalys-root</relativePath>`  but this parent is not in the jar !